# Post form into dialog window by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, onsubmit

I'm trying to make this piece of code work.

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="alert('1');"> </form>
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="document.myform.submit();">ok</a>
```

However nothing happens when I click "ok". Where have I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The browser does not trigger the `onsubmit` event if you call the `submit` method programmatically. Therefore, if the form is using the form validator script, call the `onsubmit` method also to trigger the validation.

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml (there's also an example)

So, your form is posted but `onsumbit` is not triggered.